# How to use the function numpy.append

Tags: python, numpy, append

I have a problem using the function numpy.append.
I wrote the following function as part of a larger piece of code,
however, my error is reproduced in the folowing:

```
data = [
         [
          '3.5', '3', '0', '0', '15', '6', 
          '441', 'some text', 'some more complicated data'
         ], 
         [
          '4.5', '5', '1', '10', '165', '0', 
          '1', 'some other text', 'some even more complicated data'
         ]
       ]

def GetNumpyArrey(self, index):
    r = np.array([])
    for line in data:
        np.append(r, float(line[index]))

    print r
```

index < 6.
the result is:

```
>> []
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/numpy-how-to-add-items-into-an-array

Comment: As @BrenBarn points out, there is no reason to use `numpy.append` here. The most efficient thing to do is initially allocate `r` to `len(data)`. If you don't know the length in advance (e.g. reading from a file), then @BrenBarn's suggestion of creating a list and converting to an array is best.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unlike the list `append` method, numpy's `append` does not append in-place.  It returns a new array with the extra elements appended.  So you'd need to do `r = np.append(r, float(line[index]))`.

Building up numpy arrays in this way is inefficient, though.  It's better to just build your list as a Python list and then make a numpy array at the end.