# 2D array initialization

Tags: python, numpy

I am computing an expression which I know has dimensions of `(200,200)` in one case hence I can initialize the array with
`p = np.zeros((200,200))`

what if I did not know the dimensions - is there any way to create such array without specifying the dimensions? Something like a list in java which can grow dynamically.

Comment: Without knowing the dimensions of the array there is no way to allocate memory for it. You should look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/how-to-add-items-into-a-numpy-array) for some details.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know the dimensions when you write the code, or when you run it?

Comment: Numpy arrays aren't well suited to growing dynamically. (You can `append` to them, but you're creating a new copy and deleting the old one each time.) If you have something that needs  to constantly change in size, use a `list`.  In many cases you may even want to use a list of arrays (e.g. appending rows of a constant size).  You can always convert to an array afterwards.

Comment: @jonrsharpe let's say I have p = some expression on data which I can load from a file. Different files can have different dimensions. For example, 200,200, or 500,200, etc. Hence I don't know what the dimensions will be.
Ffisegydd  Thank you for the link!
Joe - thanks!

Comment: @Tad but in that case could you use e.g. [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to load the file into an array? Then you don't have to explicitly set the size.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe This looks promising. By the way, how can you open that link? It never loads for me or any of my friends. I wonder what might cause this.

Comment: Looks like http://docs.scipy.org is down - try [the Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1XdWQmblflEJ:docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)