# How do I append a list to an empty numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a functionality that for every iteration fetches elements and appends it to a list. At the end of certain number of iterations (say 1 million) I want to append the list to a numpy array, then empty the list and continue the process.

I have declared an empty numpy array as

```
a= np.array([], dtype="int32")

b =[1,2,3,4] is my list for first 1 million iteration, 

b =[5,4,3,2] is the list for second 1 million iteration
```

how do I keep on appending the list b to the numpy array a after every 1 million iteration.

I need an output as given below

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 4, 3, 2]])
```

I have tried "concatenate" and "vstack" , but the problem is the dimension for a(when empty) and b doesn't match, so the code gives error.

The list is going to be as big as 1 million, so need an cost effective method to deal with the append. I could also "vstack" elements for each iteration, but that will load the huge list every time I vstack, which would not be cost-efficient. I tried the below code, which is working just fine but I want to avoid the check at every iteration.

```
if any(a):
    a=np.vstack((a,b))
else:
    a=np.append(a,b, axis=0)
```

Is there any way I can append a list to a numpy array without performing the check.

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5068182/1716866.

Comment: Note that appending to a numpy array is never efficient. Numpy arrays cannot grow dynamically in size, so every concatenation will create a whole new array. If you know the maximum number of iterations you could first initialize the whole matrix and just fill it row by row. A slightly uglier approach would be to store a list of numpy arrays and create the big array in the end.

Comment: If you want to append to an empty array, you have to specify its dimensions.  For instance, `np.empty((0,4))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend not appending to the array as that can be very inefficient.  Instead, you could use `deque` for collecting the lists, and make an array from that only when you need it.  Here is an example:

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np

lists = deque()
for i in range(1, 13, 4):
     lists.append(range(i, i + 4))

result = np.array(lists)
```

Now we have

```
>>> result
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

`deque` is a linked list, which means that we don't have to reallocate memory for the whole container once new elements appear.