# why is numpy.linalg.norm slow when called many times for small size data?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import math

def norm(l):
    s = 0
    for i in l:
        s += i**2
    return math.sqrt(s)

def foo(a, b, f):
    l = range(a)
    s = datetime.now()
    for i in range(b):
        f(l)
    e = datetime.now()
    return e-s

foo(10**4, 10**5, norm)
foo(10**4, 10**5, np.linalg.norm)
foo(10**2, 10**7, norm)
foo(10**2, 10**7, np.linalg.norm)
```

I got the following output:

```
0:00:43.156278
0:00:23.923239
0:00:44.184835
0:01:00.343875
```

It seems like when `np.linalg.norm` is called many times for small-sized data, it runs slower than my norm function.

What is the cause of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: `datetime.now()` isn't appropriate to measure performance, it includes the wall-time and you may just pick a bad time (for your computer) when a high-priority process runs or Pythons GC kicks in, ...

There are dedicated timing functions/modules available in Python: the built-in [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module or [`%timeit`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) in IPython/Jupyter and several other external modules (like [`perf`](http://perf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), ...)

Let's see what happens if I use these on your data:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def norm(l):
    s = 0
    for i in l:
        s += i**2
    return math.sqrt(s)

r1 = range(10**4)
r2 = range(10**2)

%timeit norm(r1)
3.34 ms ± 150 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit np.linalg.norm(r1)
1.05 ms ± 3.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit norm(r2)
30.8 µs ± 1.53 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit np.linalg.norm(r2)
14.2 µs ± 313 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It isn't slower for short iterables it's still faster. However note that the real advantage from NumPy functions comes if you already have NumPy arrays:

```
a1 = np.arange(10**4)
a2 = np.arange(10**2)

%timeit np.linalg.norm(a1)
18.7 µs ± 539 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.linalg.norm(a2)
4.03 µs ± 157 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Yeah, it's quite a lot faster now. 18.7us vs. 1ms - almost 100 times faster for 10000 elements. That means most of the time of `np.linalg.norm` in your examples was spent in converting the `range` to a `np.array`.

Comment: I just %timeit in my example, got the following:%timeit f(100, 10**5, norm), 1 loop, best of 3: 442 ms per loop. %timeit f(100, 10**5, np.linalg.norm), 1 loop, best of 3: 607 ms per loop. I thought it may because of the overhead in numpy and also converting range to np.array

Comment: I think there's something missing in your comment - or I don't understand what you want to say. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If I use numpy.array, np.linalg.norm will be faster. Thanks

Comment: @posmee Yeah, NumPy functions have the tendency to have much higher overhead than pure Python functions. But most break-even between 100 and 1000 elements. And before the break-even it's not too bad, normally just a few us slower and if you're not in a tight loop a few microseconds will be micro-optimizing (and generally not worth the trouble).

Answer (score 2):

**You are on the right way**

`np.linalg.norm` has a quite high overhead on small arrays. On large arrays both the jit compiled function and `np.linalg.norm` runs in a memory bottleneck, which is expected on a function that does simple multiplications most of the time.

If the jitted function is called from another jitted function it might get inlined, which can lead to a quite a lot larger advantage over the numpy-norm function.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def norm(l):
    s = 0.
    for i in range(l.shape[0]):
        s += l[i]**2
    return np.sqrt(s)
```

**Performance**

```
r1 = np.array(np.arange(10**2),dtype=np.int32)
Numba:0.42µs
linalg:4.46µs

r1 = np.array(np.arange(10**2),dtype=np.int32)
Numba:8.9µs
linalg:13.4µs

r1 = np.array(np.arange(10**2),dtype=np.float64)
Numba:0.35µs
linalg:3.71µs

r2 = np.array(np.arange(10**4), dtype=np.float64)
Numba:1.4µs
linalg:5.6µs
```

**Measuring Performance**

- Call the jit-compiled function one time before the measurement (there is a static compilation overhead on the first call)
- Make clear if the measurement is valid (since small arrays stays in processor-cache there may be to optimistic results exceeding your RAM throughput on realistic examples eg. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796237/4045774))