# Insert new columns into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `numpy` array in python called `my_values` of size 5x5 and a `numpy` vector which contains boolean values with size 1x90 (5 False, 85 True) naned cols_indexes. I want to expand my initial array `my_values` with zeros in the positions indexes of the cols_indexes that are equal to `False`. Thus in the end my transformed matrix `my_values` should be of size 5x90 (with 85 new columns filled with zero). A simple example that uses an array instead of a vector of Boolean's is:

```
def insert_one_per_row(arr, mask, putval):

   mask_ext = np.column_stack((mask, np.zeros((len(mask), 1), dtype=bool)))
   out = np.empty(mask_ext.shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
   out[~mask_ext] = arr.ravel()
   out[mask_ext] = putval
   return out

y = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
x = np.array([[False,  True,  False, False, False],
          [False,  True,  False, False, False],
          [False,  True,  False, False, False],
          [False,  True,  False, False, False],
          [False,  True,  False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

arr = insert_one_per_row(y, x, putval=0)
```

This example works with an array of Boolean's. However in my case `x` is a vector instead of an array. `x` contains `True` for a new column in the position that I need to add and `False` for an existing one in the position of the final array. How can I insert the new columns using the vector `x` instead of the matrix `x`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064822/how-to-add-items-into-a-numpy-array/5068182#5068182 Conclusion is that there are methods around, but it's better to start with an array as large as you're going to need and fill in values as needed.

Comment: In my case is necessary to do the opposite since I need to process the matrix without the zeros.

Comment: That happens. Do the stack functions like https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack that are there not work for your needs?

Comment: You might have a mistake in the question? You wrote you want to have zeros in "positions indexes of the cols_indexes that are equal to False", but there are 5 Falses, not 85.

Comment: Yes true I meant the opposite. I edited the question.

Comment: How about using `np.tile(x,(5,1))` to create the matrix mask from a vector `x`?

Comment: The issue is that if that matrix is bigger than the size of my my_values it does not work

Comment: In my example I can add only one column. If two columns are true then it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs - adjusted to work:

```
In [73]: y = np.arange(1,21).reshape(5, 4)
    ...: x = np.array([[False,  True,  False, False, False],
    ...:           [False,  True,  False, False, False],
    ...:           [False,  True,  False, False, False],
    ...:           [False,  True,  False, False, False],
    ...:           [False,  True,  False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
    ...:
```

The whole array masking, roughly what your function does

```
In [74]: res = np.full(x.shape, 0)    # assign the putval on creation
In [75]: res[~x] = y.ravel()
In [76]: res
Out[76]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  0,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9,  0, 10, 11, 12],
       [13,  0, 14, 15, 16],
       [17,  0, 18, 19, 20]])
```

We can use `where` to get the column indices from a 1d mask, here a row of `x`:

```
In [77]: res[:, np.where(~x[0,:])[0]]
Out[77]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20]])
```

assignment - but don't use ravel since the RHS is (4,5).  This indexing doesn't flatten array like the full boolean mask:

```
In [80]: res[:, np.where(~x[0,:])[0]] = 2*y
In [81]: res
Out[81]: 
array([[ 2,  0,  4,  6,  8],
       [10,  0, 12, 14, 16],
       [18,  0, 20, 22, 24],
       [26,  0, 28, 30, 32],
       [34,  0, 36, 38, 40]])
```